# ReactJS Call a function from another component

Tags: reactjs

This is my component and it calls the function getData which will execute an API call to the server.

```
const Page = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  async function fetchData() {
    const result = await getData();
    setData(result.data);
  }
```

The data is passed to react-table to be displayed. However, I have a modal where the user can submit a form that changes the content of the data at the backend and I would like the data to automatically update after the user submits.

What is the best way to call the `fetchData()` function from another component? React hooks, redux?

I am aware of the possibility of passing the method as props, but the modal is called by the table component which means the function would have to be passed twice.

Comment: What is the relationship between the components? Are they parent/child? If yes, who are the parent and children?

Comment: PageComponent > TableComponent > Modal (Using portal)

Comment: Thanks. And the fetched data is used in which components?

Comment: It's being fetched in the PageComponent. The data is then passed to react-table via the data props.

Comment: Anyways, did my answer manage to help you figure it out? :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend setting up redux and maintaining a state tree if it is a small application with relatively simple logic. Try not to bloat up your codebase with additional boilerplate unless necessary.

Since the data is only used in `<TableComponent />` and `<Modal />`, you can fetch the data in the `TableComponent`, and pass it to the `Modal` via props.

If you wish to fetch it in `< PageComponent />`, you can still pass the props down.